# Google Play Notification - External Storage Permission - Before May 5th 2021

Tags: android-external-storage, android-11, scoped-storage

Starting May 5th, you must let us know why your app requires broad storage access
Apr 14, 2021 10:26
Fast Story Saver Pro 2021
Fast Story Saver Pro 2021
We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs.

Developers with apps on devices running Android 11+ must use Scoped Storage to give users better access control over their device storage. To release your app on Android 11 or newer after May 5th, you must either:

Update your app to use more privacy friendly best practices, such as the Storage Access Framework or Media Store API
Update your app to declare the All files access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in the manifest file, and complete the All files access permission declaration in Play Console from May 5th
Remove the All files access permission from your app entirely
For apps targeting Android 11, the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag will be ignored. You must use the All files access permission to retain broad access.

Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a permitted use will be removed from Google Play, and you won't be able to publish updates.

21:47April 25, 2021

Anyone can help me? how can i fix?

my app API level 29. Application already required permission. see the attached screenshot. waiting for your kind response.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey Malik everybody is looking for this answer so I found this Reddit link might be helpful for you Reddit link discussion :- https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mwaqn1/scoped_storage_recap/?sort=new